# Flex: align Checkboxes horizontally, but Wrap To a New Line

Tags: apache-flex, flash, adobe

I have a form and one of the fields is a check-all-that-applies type field with several checkboxes under it. I need to display the checkboxes side by side, but since there are many, I want them to wrap to the next line.

I tried using `HGroup` inside the `FormItem` and around them all, but this displays them all on the same line without line wrapping.

```
<mx:FormItem>
  <s:HGroup>    
     <s:CheckBox content="item 1" />
     <s:CheckBox content="item 2" />
     <s:CheckBox content="item 3" />
     <s:CheckBox content="item 4" />
     <s:CheckBox content="item 5" />
     <s:CheckBox content="item 6" />
     <s:CheckBox content="item 7" />
     <s:CheckBox content="item 8" />
  </s:HGroup>   
</mx:FormItem>
```

I need them to display horizontally, but still wrap to the next line somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:Group>    
    <s:layout><s:TileLayout/></s:layout>
    <s:CheckBox content="item 1" />
    <s:CheckBox content="item 2" />
    <s:CheckBox content="item 3" />
    <s:CheckBox content="item 4" />
    <s:CheckBox content="item 5" />
    <s:CheckBox content="item 6" />
    <s:CheckBox content="item 7" />
    <s:CheckBox content="item 8" />
</s:Group>
```

Flex 4 let's you define layout on Groups inside the `<layout>` tag, and the `<TileLayout>` does what you want.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Although this doesn't solve it 100% (it tiles 2 per line), it's still the best I could find for a solution.

Comment: Hmm, Just set the Group width (eg. <s:Group width='500'>) it tiles it in rows and columns, just you need to give it enough space.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the [FlexLib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/) library. They have a component called the [FlowBox](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/FlowBox.html) which I think will do exactly what you want it to. The only thing is that I'm not sure whether FlexLib is compatible with Flex 4 yet or not.